# How can I determine what a read-only script does?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have been given the task of fixing a series of automated tasks on multiple computers. One of the computers in this automated series is an old Mac running OSX 10.4. There are some scripts on this computer that are were compiled with applescript and are read-only. I need to determine what exactly these read-only scripts are programmed to do so that I can find out which of these scripts are related to the automation process I'm looking into.

I've tried using the osadecompile command, but this only works on apps that were not saved as run-only.

Is there a way to simply find out what these scripts do? I don't need to be able to make edits to them, I just need to be able to see what they do.